# Memory leak from Apple CameraUI code

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, camera

I have used some code from Apple's 'Camera Programming Topics for iOS' guide as follows:

```
UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

// Displays a control that allows the user to only take picture:
cameraUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];

// Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;

cameraUI.delegate = delegate;

[controller presentModalViewController: cameraUI animated: YES];
[cameraUI release];
```

However, when I 'Analyze' my code, Xcode says I have a potential leak from the following line:

```
cameraUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];
```

I have no other `release` commands than those shown above. Given the array in question is an attribute of cameraUI (which is released), Im not sure what I should do (if anything).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless `cameraUI.mediaTypes` property is defined with `assign`, there is indeed a leak here.  It may help to break up the line into multiple steps, just for instruction.

```
NSArray* mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];
cameraUI.mediaTypes = mediaTypes;
```

If `cameraUI` takes care of its own memory, it shouldn't matter what you assign or when.  But, in that first line, you're constructing a variable but never releasing it.  So, how do you fix this?  The standard way to fix it is by autoreleasing during construction.

```
cameraUI.mediaTypes = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil] autorelease];
```

If you're working with very large objects that must be released as soon as possible, you'll need to manually release it once it's been passed to `cameraUI`:

```
NSArray* mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];
cameraUI.mediaTypes = mediaTypes;
[mediaTypes release];
```

Only use the second form if you need it - it's much more prone to error.

Comment: Ahh understood. Yep that's worked. Quick question though...why is the second form more susceptible to error (I have similar coding to this throughout my app).

Comment: The second form works fine when you write it, but as the program grows it's easy to put lines of code between the allocation and the release.  Then at some point you accidentally delete the release, or move it into an if statement.  The first version is much harder to accidentally break.  On the other hand, putting everything in the autorelease pool can mean you run out of memory before the pool gets drained...

Comment: ahh yes - that all makes sense now. So it's susceptible to human error!! Thanks